# Вывести каждое изображение с конкретным id в цикле

Tags: python

Есть 3 ссылки на изображение (список imgs) и 3 id, привязанных к ним (тоже список, offer_ids). Сортировать ничего не нужно, они упорядочены друг относительно друга. Но как вывести их в цикле?
Я новичок в Python.

```
img = self.get_argument("img", None)
    if len(img) > 0:
        imgs = img.split(',')
offer_id = self.get_argument("offer_id", None)
    if len(offer_id) > 0:
        offer_ids = offer_id.split(',')
```

Как их объединить, чтобы было что-то вроде:

```
for img, offer_id in imgs, offer_id:
```

А дальше проходимся по первым элементам в списках, вторым, третьим...

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
for index, url in enumerate(imgs):
    print('<img src="{}" id="{}">'.format(url, offer_ids[index]))
```

Или так

```
for url, img_id in zip(imgs, offet_ids):
    print('<img src="{}" id="{}">'.format(url, img_id))
```

Comment: Мой ответ вам подойдёт.

Comment: Второе идеально, большое спасибо!